# How to stop Bazel from trying to download packages in offline environment

Tags: bazel

Bazel is trying to download packages on python test. I've wrote a simple python code, and a test file testing it.
I'm running `bazel test //test:python-test and I get the following error:
/Path/to/build/external/bazel_tools/tools/jdk/build:305:1: no such package '@remotejdk_linux//': java.io.IOException: error downloading [ unknown host: mirror.bazel.build and referenced by '@bazel_tools//tools/jdk:remote_jdk'
Now, that's obviously a problem in my workspace, where we work offline. Is there any way to work offline with bazel?

Comment: Found 2 flags that solves this: `--host_javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk: absolute_javabase --define=ABSOLUTE_JAVABASE=/path/to/my/jdk` solved this. Can I make my bazel command now less bloated without aliasing?

Comment: FWIW, I also found https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/6656 containing some useful information on how the JDK is selected and pulled in (or taken from host).

Answer (score 0):

Using the following flags will force bazel to use your local java:
`--host_javabase=@bazel_tools//tools/jdk: absolute_javabase --define=ABSOLUTE_JAVABASE=/path/to/my/jdk`
You can add them to your local .bazelrc file to write shorter command-line

Answer (score 0):

You can manually download requested artifact and put it in cache before calling build. Bazel will not download artifact if it's already exists in local cache.